# *ngFor with local assignment with the async pipe and reducing number of subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I have code similar to the following in the template file of a custom Angular component I have written:

```
<item
    [class.disabled]="domain?.disabled | async"
    [class.hidden]="!(domain?.subscribed | async) && !showHiddenDomains || (domain?.deleted | async)"
    [disabled]="domain?.disabled | async"
    [hideHealth]="true"
    *ngFor="let domain of (forest?.domains | async)"
    [status]="domain?.status | async"
    (expand)="collapseDomain($event, domain)">
    <span header>
        <div [class.container-disabled]="!(domain?.disabled | async) && !(domain?.iconType | async)">
            <spinner-2 [promise]="spinnerPromise" *ngIf="domain?.disabled | async"></spinner-2>
            <font-icon class="domain-header-icon-{{domain?.statusString | async}}" [type]="domain?.iconType | async" *ngIf="!(domain?.disabled | async)"></font-icon>
        </div>
        <div>{{domain.name}}</div>
    </span>
    .
    .
    .
```

I've been reading [this](https://fluin.io/blog/attack-of-the-async-pipe) article and am wondering if I can take advantage of the `*ngIf with local assignment` discussed at the bottom of the page. I read this:

> Here we are creating a local template variable that Angular assigns
>   the value from the Observable. This allows us to interact directly
>   with our user Object without having to use the async pipe over and
>   over.

On [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else) page and was wondering if I could take advantage of this so that I do not have to keep reusing the async pipe over and over again as I feel it is drastically reducing performance on my page.

Thoughts? Thanks

***UPDATE***

I've been able to reduce most of the code to this fashion by wrapping `ng-containers` around blocks of code, for example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="forest?.domains | async as domains">
    <div *ngFor="let domain of domains">
        .
        .  
        .
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Some of these domains have properties attached to them that are in the form of:

```
property: Observable.from([true]);
```

Anyone know what the above does?

Comment: I think this is what you want - https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Comment: is `forrest.domains` an array of `Observable`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of the `domain` object in the `domains` are subscribable entries.

Just create a component called `ItemHeader` as below and dumb down the subscriptions into one.

Change your html as below

```
<item
    [class.disabled]="domain?.disabled | async"
    [class.hidden]="!(domain?.subscribed | async) && !showHiddenDomains || (domain?.deleted | async)"
    [disabled]="domain?.disabled | async"
    [hideHealth]="true"
    *ngFor="let domain of (forest?.domains | async)"
    [status]="domain?.status | async"
    (expand)="collapseDomain($event, domain)">
    <item-header [domain]="domain | async"></item-header>
    .
    .
    .
```

//item-header.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item-header',
  templateUrl: './item-header.component.html'
})
export class ItemHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() domain: Domain 
 constructor(){}

}
```

//item-header.component.html

```
<span header>
        <div [class.container-disabled]="!(domain?.disabled | async) && !(domain?.iconType | async)">
            <spinner-2 [promise]="spinnerPromise" *ngIf="domain?.disabled | async"></spinner-2>
            <font-icon class="domain-header-icon-{{domain?.statusString | async}}" [type]="domain?.iconType | async" *ngIf="!(domain?.disabled)"></font-icon>
        </div>
        <div>{{domain.name}}</div>
    </span>
```